# Can laptops run without a Cmos Battery

Tags: motherboard, battery, hp-pavilion, laptop-repair, cmos

So while I start the process of getting a new cmos battery. Will my laptop run without one if I remove the old one? Since a lot of you said it might leak can I remove it and still run?

Comment: The process is… "walk to nearest supermarket or watch or phone shop, get battery, walk home" Sure, it will work in the meantime but you'll have to set the BIOS up every time you power it up.

Comment: No I have laptop from 2007 or 2009 and it uses an a plug to connect to the board so not easy. If I leave the laptop plugged into wall will it still need to set the bios? What does set the bios mean?

Comment: Yeah, I just found your other question - it still looks like a 2032 in a wrap. Leaving it plugged in the wall wil not help. if the battery still has enough charge to hold the date, then don't take it out until the new one arrives.

Comment: Ok. Are 2032 rechargeable? Because mine seem to be. Because when I leave it plugged in and then disconnect from wall I notice it still has correct time and date? But it does that for a while before time gets wrong while still plugged in and windows is on.

Comment: No, they're pretty standard alkaline, afaik. They cost pence - your buck premium is because someone cheapskated the standard clip-in mount & made it some frankenstien plug-in instead.

Comment: Thanks! Is the best way to find out what I have is to find one exactly so I don't ruin mine. Or can I buy the adapter with wire and then just by the battery you said?

Comment: I believe that 2032 are lithium batteries. The battery will say on it what size it is etc.

Comment: To be able to DIY you need to know the precise spec of the battery.

Comment: @Ack - yup, checked, Lithium… but rechargeable?? If they are, how does that work for the millions of devices - car keys etc, that never see a 'charger' of any type? [I honestly don't know, my battery skillset doesn't extend that far] btw, 2032 IS the size, 20x3.2mm

Comment: @Tetsujin This is true, they are not rechargeable. I'm not sure why you think I said that, I didn't say that they are rechargeable just correcting your assertion that they are alkaline.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I posted one comment then quickly checked where I may have been confused.

Comment: I dont think they are. But because its wrapped and I did not peel it i thought it was some special kind. I guess my idea would work if i buy one spare online then open it up and buy a regular battery and connect it. That way connection is old battery is new. Any recommendations where or Ebay and amazon are my best bet?

Comment: Just look it up based on your laptop brand and model. I think Tetsujin mentioned that you have another post about the battery?

Comment: In my experience, for a very long time now desktop motherboards have soldered-on CMOS batteries (good for a decade or so, so...). Laptops are mostly so cramped there just is't space for luxuries like "replaceable".

Comment: I was able to remove it but put it back

Answer (score 2):

> Will my laptop run without one if I remove the old one?

Yes, but not the way that you want. It is what gives power to the item that keeps your current date and time, and other important settings that you don't want to set each time  you start your computer.

> Since a lot of you said it might leak...?

This is a possibility but is also uncommon for button batteries.

In the end, replace your battery with the same type. The battery will say on it what size it is. If you want to buy the battery before opening up your computer you can look it up by searching for the specs for your laptop.